# Turn HTML to JIRA compatible text

Tags: c#, .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I've have a text editor in a web application similar to what we have here in StackOverflow. It returns text as HTML (Bold is   etc). What a user enters in that editor then should be sent to JIRA with the correct styling. However, I couldn't find anything in .NET that is going to help me achieve this and I couldn't make a simple find and replace strategy work for
<ol> <li> or <ul> <li>.

Link for the formatting that I need to follow when sending to JIRA's API
https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all

Comment: so, just to be clear, you are asking for a [tag:html] to [tag:markdown] converter? a quick googling *"c# html to markdown converter"* should do the trick if its so. also, depending on your "text editor", some may output markdown if told to.

Comment: @BagusTesa if you check the link it is basically markdown yeah, but for example for bold, it does * * bold * * instead of * bold * which is what JIRA wants